# How to decide the number of layers?

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I am new to PCB design and I want to understand how exactly we should select the number of layers. I just know more layers helps us with making the routing easy but I don't understand what is power plane, ground plane etc and how they are related to the traces which are going in the PCB. Circuit is of a double pulse test setup. [image]